# How I can read xml not written by openCV

Tags: opencv

For detection, I need to read number of points in xml file which was not written by openCV

so it starts like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KisaLibraryIndex>
....
<KisaLibraryIndex>
```

I tried to read this xml file using

```
FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
```

but it wasn't work with error message "abort() has been called"

I think the library index isn't matching with `<opencv storage>`

Is it impossible to read xml file doesn't written in openCV ::WRITE???

Comment: You've omitted the crucial part of the XML file...

Comment: Can you explain briefly what I omitted??

Comment: there are many libraries to read xml files, like tinyXML. You can't expect openCV to read any custom data...

Comment: You omitted the part where it tells you the number of points. Or examples of some points if the file just shows you the points and leaves you to count them yourself.